# Erverse Hte Ifrst Wto Eltters fo Aech Owrd

Tags: code-golf, string

> *Inspired by [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61463602#61463602) accidental misspelling*

If you could read the title, then you already know what the challenge is about. If not, then I'll tell you. Easy: simply take each word (single space delimited), and swap the positions of the first two letters. You may assume that the input will contain only lowercase ASCII letters and spaces and that there will be no one-letter words. You many optionally take a list of words instead of a sentence.

### Testcases

```
hello world -> ehllo owrld
this is an easy challenge -> htis si na aesy hcallenge
reverse the first two letters of each word -> erverse hte ifrst wto eltters fo aech owrd
pptx is one of ooxml format -> pptx si noe fo ooxml ofrmat
(empty) -> (empty)
```

### Leaderboard

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 249523; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 107299; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() > b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() < b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block !important;
}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/all.css?v=ffb5d0584c5f">
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can we assume there are no consecutive spaces, and/or that the string does not start or end with a space? (i.e. there are no "zero-length words")

Comment: If the input is just single-space-separated words, why not simply [allow a list of words](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/43319)? And if so, why require list processing and not just [give a single word as input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/43319)?

Comment: [Very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185674/pwas-eht-tirsf-dna-tasl-setterl-fo-hace-dorw).

Comment: @Adám I’ll do the word list but tbh I wasn’t planning to add any fluff to this challenge, it’s just the way I thought of it. Besides, I’m not gonna change the specs with 15 answers already lol

Comment: @pxeger yes. You may

Comment: shouldn't it be "Ofr" instead of "fo"?

Comment: @BЈовић `of` -> `fo`

Comment: @Seggan oh sorry. I thought it was "for" > "ofr"

Comment: Can I mix list and string I/O? e.g. take input as a list of words, and output a space separated string

Comment: @noodleman sure

Answer (score 17):

## x86-64 machine code, 12 bytes

```
B0 20 66 C1 07 08 AE 72 FD 74 F7 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJha9swFPxs/YqbR6jcJqXtyijNvC/b17ERBhskKSjys60hS0ZS2pTSvz7vOVk3VjoQlnzv7t6hJz1rtB4GFTtILHIpThvrN8qiFvW1yDp/C2WnOMKRcLRLdz5UDAdv8e3z4iO@fF1gGSqznuJqT7CUEgWmRK3iRmQ/NvgL8y/hyYZdKIkiRzEXulUBtdxvx5EB8do4bbcV4V1MlfGn7ft/oGBcM2LGJXTKOFmIB5Ht9XF5fnG1novsrjWWIDmIq2U@Wd6s3Br5FLFAWeK8EBlLslqO/bKs36Z4OD6KrGf/xKKV@6R0axxB@4qu87GsvYsJWxdN46jCIXOPEvLFSlHPn0GaTSqPpx6YnF1851i6PO5PToo5fufWeFXibPfhzdj0D1lODDb3iWKxcizqZ//ryqrHYWjJWg@@bluJ1JoIXsqBVLwfmdaSa0gEuqUQCakl1CawHU8Ih5lF@Jr5usV@aH2fdqOJ5zvhgve7jt@KD51K4qeurWriMOveXvKH31TJqcn@Ag)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes the address of the input, as a null-terminated byte string, in RDI, and modifies the string in place.

In assembly:

```
f:
    mov al, ' '     # Set AL to the ASCII code of the space.
nextword:
    rol WORD PTR [rdi], 8   # Rotate 2 bytes at the address RDI left by 8 bits.
                            # This swaps the current and next characters.
nextletter:
    scasb           # Compare AL with the current character, advancing the pointer.
    jb nextletter   # Jump back if AL is less than the character read.
    je nextword     # Jump back further if AL is equal to the character read.
    ret             # Return (if AL is greater than the character read).
```

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εΣN≠
```

-1 byte thanks to *@CommandMaster*

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##NYzNDcIwDIV3yZlZWABxMMUlkdy4si1aRmALJGZgjQ7BIsEO6uX9yM8fK1wKtrZ9tvfx@3y1dkoZiTgd0sJCV3fLRd26QHVB0IfbkIEI6w09C95RFPs6dCyiFm0JEqGZnz3x2P@H/OcHfp5t3fFccR8xrxMFiWUCS@cf)

**Explanation:**

```python
ε     # Map over each word of the (implicit) input-list:
 Σ    #  (Stable) sort its characters by:
  N   #   Where the 0-based index
   ≠  #   Is not 1
      # (after which the list of modified words is output implicitly)
```

The `N≠` will make the 0-based indices of the characters in each word `[1,0,1,1,1,...]`, basically putting the second character at the front.

Comment: alternative 6 bytes: ```εR`sJR```, and ```εΣNNiÍ```

Comment: 5 bytes: [`εΣN<Ä`](https://tio.run/##NYzNDcIwDIV3yZkRmIEFEAdTXBLJjSvbouXOJszABNy7UrCDenk/8vPHCteCrW2f7X06fl@tnVNGIk6HtLDQzd1yUbcuUF0Q9Ok2ZCDCekfPgg8Uxb4OHYuoRVuCRGjmZ0889v8h//mBn2dbdzxX3EfM60RBYpnA0uUH) or equivalently `εΣN1α`

Comment: alternative 5 bytes: `εć.ιJ`

Comment: @CommandMaster Thanks for the 5-byters. And the sort-by approach actually opened up another save with `εΣN≠`. :)

Answer (score 9):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 4 bytes

```
òxpW
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///CmioLw//89UnNy8hXK84tyUhQy8ssVEotSFSrzSwE)

Explanation:

```
ò       # Recursively...
 x      #   Delete one letter
  p     #   Paste the last deleted letter
   W    #   Move forward one word
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 30 bytes

*Thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh) for -4 bytes.*

```
,[>,.<[.[-<++++++++>]<[,>]<],]
```

Explanation:

```
,[                loop every word
  >,.             print second character of word
  <[              loop through next letters of word including first one
    .             print next letter
    [-<++++++++>] multiply the letter by 8 (8*32=256; 256%256=0)
    <[            check if the result is zero
      ,>          if not then load next letter
    ]<
  ]
,]
```

Characters `@` and `` ` `` can also be used as word separators as `8*64=512; 512%256=0` and `8*96=768; 768%256=0`.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70yqSgxMy-tNDl7wYKlpSVpuhb7dKLtdPRsovWidW20ocAu1iZaB0jE6sRCFEHVLlidkZqTk69Qnl-UkwIRAgA)

Comment: Is `,[>,.<.,[.[-<++++++++>]<[,>]<],]` works?

Comment: Thank you, it works. I think it might cause issues after 15k words, but that can probably be ignored.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
żḢF)
```

A monadic Link that takes, as allowed in the comments, a list of words and yields a list of words.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///onoc7Frlp/n@4Y9Phdu///4tSy1KLilMVSjJSFdIyi4pLFErK8xVyUktKgMIK@WkKqYnJGQrl@UUpAA)**

#### How?

```
żḢF) - Link: list of lists of characters, words  e.g. [..., "upend", ...]
   ) - for each word:                                       
 Ḣ   -   head (word) -> remove and get the first character  "u"
ż    -   (beheaded word) zip with (head character)          ["pu","e","n","d"]
  F  -   flatten that back into to a list of characters     "puend"
```

Also requires no empty words, also allowed in the comments (as `Ḣ` would yield a zero).

Note: I would say that the `F` is necessary since without this flatten a callable link would return each new word as a list of lists of characters while as a full program it would smash the characters together when it prints.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <strike>9</strike> <strike>8</strike> <strike>5</strike> 4 bytes

- x bytes thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

```
ƛḣ$Y
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGm+G4oyRZIiwiIiwiW1wicmV2ZXJzZVwiLCBcInRoZVwiLCBcImZpcnN0XCIsIFwidHdvXCIsIFwibGV0dGVyc1wiLCBcIm9mXCIsIFwiZWFjaFwiLCBcIndvcmRcIl0iXQ==) | [`S` Flag to join by spaces](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJTIiwiIiwixpvhuKMkWSIsIiIsIltcInJldmVyc2VcIiwgXCJ0aGVcIiwgXCJmaXJzdFwiLCBcInR3b1wiLCBcImxldHRlcnNcIiwgXCJvZlwiLCBcImVhY2hcIiwgXCJ3b3JkXCJdIl0=)

### Explanation

```
ƛḣ$Y
ƛ     Map through each word
 ḣ    Push all but the first letter and the first letter
  $   Swap the first two elements
   Y  Interleave
```

Comment: @Steffan ah nice

Comment: @Steffan but you still have to output a string?

Comment: @Steffan shh hopefully nobody'll notice

Comment: @Steffan oh wow

Comment: @Steffan the heck I give up

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\b(\S)(.)/g,'$2$1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZCxbsMgEED3fsUpihSQWlvtnn5AhnbImoWSw1BhzoJTHH@9e8RdmkYJYkK8dzy@zckUm8PAL4mOOLvtXLbvpck4RGNRtYcvddhr1ei2e96s39avGz1bSoUiNpE65dTKY4wEI@V4XGkND1bbAvoK0CjA05WLfSgg2yRAUyaw3sSIqcObZnF5ltslQDJgUABvf4Frc8YT5oLAHsGFXBh4JIjILMdATuZZXysuEfWVeQE8IwRXgZEJMC6AI5kngFT8ixgGPtcISljFROc@CpB7wzcyZNQFqBGEVbwA5Crwx73bf340hXNIXXBTHSU@ff@zFfYDT7BQev4B)

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
{pᶠkt↔}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYw9DsIwDIXvkpmJ44AY0uA2FW4cORZthViZGTgAlyj3KRcJTlCX9yM/fw1b52ekbp/zLa6f90W@j9d9XZ45H40HRDI7MxLjWV18n9Sq2KACNs1qzltECB1oZrgCJ6jrom3PSUobCwlBRM@aqK3/zv/5BR@jTBueAmwjomnAQiIerJhTPvwA)

An extremely stupid solution but shorter than my initial, more straightforward idea.

*-1 byte thanks to @UnrelatedString with an event stupider idea*

#### Explanation

```
{     }ᵐ    Map for each word:
 pᶠ           Find all permutations of the word
   kt         Get the penultimate one
     ↔        Reverse it
```

This works because `p` will always try permutations in the same order, and it happens that the penultimate one is the input in reverse order, with the last two characters swapped. It also works for 2 letter words because the penultimate permutation here will be the first one, i.e. the identity, and reversing it is the same as swapping the two characters.

Comment: [Even more stupid for 8](https://tio.run/##NYw9DsIwDIXvkpmJ44AY0uA2FW4cORZthViZGTgAlyj3KRcJTlCX9yM/fw1b52ekbp/zLa6f90W@j9d9XZ45H40HRDI7MxLjWV18n9Sq2KACNs1qzltECB1oZrgCJ6jrom3PSUobCwlBRM@aqK3/zv/5BR@jTBueAmwjomnAQiIerJhTPvwA)

Comment: @UnrelatedString lmao

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org/), 35 bytes

*Thanks to [steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan) for -34 bytes.*

```
lambda a:[x[1::-1]+x[2:]for x in a]
```

[Try it out](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3lXMSc5NSEhUSraIrog2trHQNY7Uroo2sYtPyixQqFDLzFBJjIUr3FBRl5pVopGlEq2ek5uTkq-soqJfnF-WkqMdqakKULFgAoQE)

p.s. This is my first serious attempt at Code Golf all feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer. You've already golfed things great, but you can remove a bit of whitespace, remove the `list(...)`, and use a list comprehension (and save 2 more bytes with a generator comprehension) for [55](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3zQuKMvNKNJQUlPSy8jPzNCqiDa2sdA1jtSuijaxi0_KLFCoUMvOAqKC0RENTr7ggJxNIa2pCtENNWbA6IzUnJ1-hPL8oJwUiBAA). Or with input and output as a list of words, [35](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3lXMSc5NSEhUSraIrog2trHQNY7Uroo2sYtPyixQqFDLzFBJjIUr3FBRl5pVopGlEq2ek5uTkq-soqJfnF-WkqMdqakKULFgAoQE). :)

Comment: Thanks @Steffan I've been a lurker here for over a year now lol I've always seen you around in the comments. Thanks for the great work and helping out!

Answer (score 6):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), <del>28</del> 25 bytes (13×2=26 codels)

```
tU?QjCuJsNrMbQvQsQjIJjMmm
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJw1TFuOwzAIvArim0hxH2qaq6T9sFJSRyJ2ZNNtV6u9--J0i9AMMMP84JhujP0wtHS80uA6Ohh15Op2pM5wTyfDHTlXDYfN4Dbcf8ztm85v2nyu8pWw8Io9Nk2DhDIvNrvWyjYuI_aTl8KEc1wfalpgkQTPlOV2ifZ0iRrmAtY-AvvyDWPwIhzv_K9n_uJcGDQwTHMuCvpMIKxqZ0iTfY2hJn4C11VfNTBFrnJKr0VgSnnxir9_Yt1TIw)

[image: Diagram]

−3 by switching to a vertical layout, allowing two white codels to be removed and one black codel to be implicit.

The program starts with *in(char), in(char), out(char), out(char)*, taking the first two letters from the input and outputting them in reversed order.

After that, it enters a loop:

- *in(char), duplicate, out(char)*: Read the next character from the input, and output it while leaving a copy on the stack.
- *push[3], duplicate, multiply, duplicate, multiply, push[1], add*: Create the value 82 on the stack.
- *divide*: Divide the character code by 82. This produces 1 for lowercase letters (97–122) and 0 for a space (32).
- *pointer*: Rotate the Direction Pointer clockwise by the value on the stack.

  - For lowercase letters, this sends execution rightwards and executes *subtract, out(char)*, which does nothing with the stack empty, before repeating the loop.
  - For spaces, execution continues upwards into the white area and returns to the start of the program to process the next word.
  - When the end of the input is reached, *in(char), duplicate, out(char)* does nothing and leaves the stack empty. The calculation of 82 still works, but then the *divide* does nothing because there is only one value on the stack, and the *pointer* rotates the Direction Pointer by 82, which is congruent to 2 modulo 4, sending it downwards. None of the reversed instructions are *push*es, so they all do nothing (because the stack is empty), and execution reaches the halting structure at the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `--extendedglob`, 29 bytes

```
<<<${@/(#m)??/`rev<<<$MATCH`}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjU7SSrm5qRUlqXkpqSnpOfpJS7E294tQShaLUstSi4lSFkoxUhbTMouIShZLyfIWc1JISoLBCfppCamJyhkJ5flHK0tKSNF2LvTY2NirVDvoayrma9vb6CUD9IBFfxxBnj4RaiJoFUApKAwA)

Zsh's pattern matching is pretty limited.

-1 byte thanks to @GammaFunction.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 28 bytes

```
\(x)sub("(.)(.)","\\2\\1",x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBSgQxDIbx6lOEemlhV9CTF32SwlLH1A5kJkObdWafxcso-BY-iU9javeyIwRawvf_-ZP3j7x-xsevo8T9w7e3iyvHZ2vsrdMyO-P9vfd3Zre4hvxcHaJFskVymagXaxISMcyc6UV5MM65G9g_Aaba51n71xuJpL6AVhgBQzlBlwIRjq94YZBEkdLDGCCgUqk7U1u7jG-YC4IkhNjnIiAzA6GItoGjDulSTbgJmJssCUIfq2wWBqQmi6xTVaYL_Ms_TbLU_DxitWdeBlJBHoJcTPjj6gaM1a9xHCunlsYoZXGY5OQqff62O69re38B)

Simple regex-breast, errr..., I mean... regex-based solution.

Takes input as a vector of words - this works nicely as `sub` is vectorised over the 3rd argument.

Comment: And `gsub` nicely handles multiple matches so you could take `\(x)gsub('( |^)(.)(.)','\\1\\3\\2',x,F,T)`
 to the space-delimited string input.

Comment: @CongChen you're right, but it's [tag:code-golf] and it's shorter that way ;-) (Also `\(x)gsub('\\b(\\S)(.)','\\2\\1',x,,T)` would be shorter for the whole sentence input)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 28 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.map{|w|(w.slice!1)+w}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjLCYAwDADQVaInRSw4gC4iHvykWKi0JNEg2tmr7/joXO5s@9wO/LA55vi8@lZq2LsVi65uNKUcwY4l4YXECLIjWEcsIBrAo8jfECzgvO6ggbbScPROpvwB)

Comment: Ruby 3+, -1 byte ->s{s.map{(_1.slice!1)+_1}} [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuha7de2Kq4v1chMLqjXiDfWKczKTUxUNNbXjDWtrISpumhcopEUrFaWWpRYVpyqUZKQqpGUWFZcolJTnK-SklpQAhRXy0xRSE5MzFMrzi1KU9IoLcjJLYiHaFyyA0AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), <s>18</s> <s>14</s> 9 bytes

```
\b\w.
⌽⍵M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCsIwEEX3OcVf1o2gXicIoZmYwjRTJ6NtwbvHBN7q/8d7f0LU1qbnD5fpOnD@5h/@3lomZsEuytFZXio6oYBCPTHnwEzlRU7pS1oJlglp0WqwXcBk1mdI6v6cRyW6bbNjRKTQOESOlZFE12DuDw)

PCRE **R**eplace:

`\b` a word boundary

`\w` any word character, and then

`.` any character

with:

`⌽⍵M` the reversed Match

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 6 bytes

OP [seems](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249523/erverse-hte-ifrst-wto-eltters-fo-aech-owrd?noredirect=1#comment556971_249523) to have allowed input as a list, so here goes…

```
⌽@1 2¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU07DsIwDN05RTfDgAScgKtYrUMquXWVRLQwMjAgQCzcgQOwsnCUXCQkRVW7PNvP74MNL4sjlhUG5c@PefDXz3adbb6vsJj5@zNyKgNNzAIZtGK4gJF3urSR7gHrCIT2EEeukZnqHU20hvZkLEFyJVSlsS5dbUpmci6@4yaqz8n1v29a1zSuG@qkpkEs0lWcEsVU6Eb9yt/e/nICCD8)

`⌽` reverse

`@` at indices

`1 2` one and two

`¨` for each word

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to DLosc*

```
⌽⌾(2⊸↑)¨
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=UmV2Rmlyc3QyIOKGkCDijL3ijL4oMuKKuOKGkSnCqAoKeCDihpAg4p+oInJldmVyc2UiLCJ0aGUiLCJmaXJzdCIsInR3byIsImxldHRlcnMiLCJvZiIsImVhY2giLCJ3b3JkIuKfqQpSZXZGaXJzdDIgeA==)

```
         ¨   # for each element of input
⌽            # reverse
 ⌾           # under
  (2⊸↑)      # take first 2 elements
```

The [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/) 'under' modifier applies a function (here, take first 2 elements) and then applies another function on the result (here, reverse), and finally undoes the first function (so, it 'undoes' taking elements 1&2, thereby putting the result back into these positions).
Think 'operating under anaesthetic', where the anaesthetic is done before the operation and undone afterwards.

Comment: Because Under is pure magic, it also works with Take: [8 bytes](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=UmV2Rmlyc3QyIOKGkCDijL3ijL4oMuKKuOKGkSnCqAoKeCDihpAg4p+oInJldmVyc2UiLCJ0aGUiLCJmaXJzdCIsInR3byIsImxldHRlcnMiLCJvZiIsImVhY2giLCJ3b3JkIuKfqQpSZXZGaXJzdDIgeA==)

Comment: @DLosc - wonderful, thanks!

Comment: That's a very nice extension of "Under" that does not work in J

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p040`, 13 bytes

Uses `-040` to work on each space separated section so that the replacement can be one off avoiding the need for `/g`, which makes it possible to use the implicit `;` from `-p` as the terminating separator.

```perl
s;(.)(.);$2$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7/YWkNPE4isVYxUDP//z0jNyclXKM8vykn5l19QkpmfV/xft8DAxAAA)

Comment: There's a tip for abusing the `{}` created by `-p`... but not for `;`; maybe there should be?

Comment: @Neil Huh. I could've sworn I learned about that from the tips! I'll add something, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 4):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-r`, 17 bytes

```
s/\<(.)(.)/\2\1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WD/GRkNPE4j0Y4xiDPXT//8vycgsVgCixDyF1MTiSoXkjMScnNS89NR/@QUlmfl5xf91iwA)

Uses the rare 'start of word' marker `\<`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
unwords.map(\(a:b:c)->b:a:c).words
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCoAgEEbhq8zSFnkAwU7S5s/GlGwKNaLTmwQPvsULKDun1A5EIUtRKme4Sr55e8tz5rXoAxepWcEsxg3jtBh09f9aqyEW6kGIUV5yASmxbPwB)

Comment: (I'm pretty sure) as this is a pure function submission, you don't have to count the `f=`

Comment: @emanresuA Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), <sup><s>10</s> <s>7</s></sup> 6 bytes

```
U2œ?U)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FstDjY5Otg_VXFKclFy8-HC7N0T4pnu0UrR6UWpZalFxqrqOgnpJBphKyywqLgHzy_NBVE5qSQlQCYiZnwYiUxOTM0B0eX5RinqsUizUGgA)

-3 bytes by doing I/O as a list rather than a space-separated string, now that the OP has allowed that.

-1 thanks to @Unrelated String

Explanation:

Given a word \$ a_n \cdots a_3 a_2 a_1 \$, the permutation \$ a_n \cdots a_3 a_1 a_2 \$ is at index 2 in the list of permutations of that word.

```
     )       map over each word:
U            reverse
 2œ?         index 2 into all permutations of the reversed input
    U        (un-)reverse
```

Comment: [6](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FstDjY5Otg_VXFKclFy8-HC7N0T4pnu0UrR6UWpZalFxqrqOgnpJBphKyywqLgHzy_NBVE5qSQlQCYiZnwYiUxOTM0B0eX5RinqsUizUGgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 48 bytes

*Thanks to user `Kalobi` for -3 bytes and `pxeger` for another -3 bytes.*

```python
print(*(i[1::-1]+i[2:]for i in input().split()))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BDoJADEX3c4qGFWgw4spwFcOCYHGalOlkpgiexY0Lde11vI1DMPnJb9rf197f_qZW3OMzWWKEqsYZuzzLsteofXn87n0gp_kmp1NV12XVbOl0qJteAhCQS_Kj5sUueqbkRbHuPRPhXz6-ziKzwCSBz0YtRUhqHWAbb9DZlhndBU3AK4aIoBahpxAVdBJgVE1tkD7lO7tQzsZ7nReIOFwGIvPAkH4aWjVmPfsD)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 7 bytes

```
V`\b\w.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBDsMgDATvvMIvqNTP9JRDnWQpSA6OjBWS11OQ5rSzGoPnwu/eP99lXdqr9wQRpaYme/CUKw24ELg@tCUWQfkhGC5YBXkCxWzVyZuSwH3MpHH8tzQrezhPv2dEC6ZQvQ@hqHawhz8) Link includes test cases. Explanation: A simple use of Retina's reVerse command on the first two letters of each word.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("\\b(\\S)(.)","$2$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY6xCoMwGIR3n@InOCSggXa1Fbp06@RYO0SNbexvEky0SPHZbYpOd3DHfdeJSaTGSt0177VG4RzchNLwjQCcF17V0IUKH71C3o669spoft3NqfCD0s8ENs2hhfPq0tzxQVoUtbwgUlKWFS3LglHOSELiY3wgbM2iQLBjhYGwgyajGugDnW5z9wcI9j8Cxey87LkZPbch8ahpy4W1OFPykogGPmbAhjCWhfoSLesP)

-1 thanks to @KevinCruijssen

Couldn't come up with a less boring version. The shortest other idea I had was just swapping `i+1` and `i+2` in an array where index `i` is a space, but just `toCharArray()` is 13 chars :(

Comment: You can remove the space for -1 byte.

Comment: Also I think the rules allow for taking a `char[][]` instead of a `String[]` if needed

Comment: @KevinCruijssen lol, I'm an idiot! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

```
:\<2@>2@
```

```
           # implicit map over input:
:          # append
 \         # the reverse of
  <2@      # take first 2 characters of each arg
           # onto
     >2@   # drop first 2 characters from each arg
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 36 bytes

```java
l->l.peek(s->s[0]^=s[1]^(s[1]=s[0]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDBahsxEL37K6YLAW2xRXu144USmltOPjoOqOuRV45WEppZ20vJt6uSvS2YFCQN897Me6M5qpNaHPfvyfTBR4ZjzuXAxsqvq9knTA@uZePdf0niiKovVGsVEbwo4@D3DCAMv6xpgVhxDidv9tBnTmw4GnfY7kDFA9XXUoDnyeJxc5V7bDsVt7tmfp82oGGd7KKxMiC@C1o0tP22e1vT9vvuTZR3XYC6TqurrPYRxEnF4gXLO0eAghOs4eYhvRaZlxSsYVFBVddSG8sYxWXRfLlIQz/7wKPIeK/C9I3lkv1THu5HjGqsV5NyUdVShWBHQf/Q4heRBsuZpjsRh@datt5abFk83aKPJI/euFxwG@evzmYkxjzvwDLkdtaieq0e6LVawi0@uGpe/jqf7KbOj1m5Hyl1aK2Hs492n7gzBPkoB6hohLzp7O4OmCKeMBICdwjaRGLgsweLnFdC4HWub7uisk8h8KWIeIeF8P7S27L7XnH6Aw)

- Takes input as `Stream<char[]>`, and returns another `Stream<char[]>`, with each `char[]` being a word.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

```
{x@>1=!#x}'
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qucLAztFVUrqhV5+JKc1BSUIpRykjNyclXKM8vyklRyMgvV0gsSlWozC9VAgA7oA49)

Answer (score 3):

## Knight, 78 bytes

```
;=s+" "P;=i~1;=r"";W<=i+1iLs=r+r+=gGs i 1I?g" ";=i+2i+Gs i 1Gs-i 1 1""O Gr 1Lr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4pBKWzJlhNJcFVblmWKZIGilkAWkssH8AUhy/bUybJPkmFZQv56rrtnRhrZJne5WyplWTPP9MszPd09TtSbRtH3VzyNktU4HuTFmC9ez4ZNfSThd7WhqHhcxmugjKfT2lDB5wIzjic8jVmSsGSRTumjWY5@PP/0nrnV69XHS@ZVr38/vGT71evx@Tv2S/V6@Ym5Ffj47ErDnn8606Cfzt8fXv1m5hYz8aPFvrl/s8rZwytQKyajWZixjlUt0FFgayliOGT71dz50WecTGGSPPrK8PtgsIZBNYRBNwGTJBYCa5i3FxdnBMKPA3Kyj75phlyeCACs12y9D5NVbFnX6chqNskP2JXrUXBpHF0cm9/9IO8azPjgB/yb6weZYfifBwHvuvwsD7Ju1g2mJznjzD09mAIOYF2Pd8XQSd6DT@YaxgU7yZh7ln23QKjhCz0dUBSHcxagRr/ZBLOWYZbHpsWemg2eFoz7zQaMkok260xWaQQjtDiC92K@tPNleu2NgifHdp5BRoODOMLD08GBN29QPF@yhxkv4nwZRnGzAd@T2IRxWG4KM2xm3BQ36c3kJmNPz9cj0@q/MiwypcEnzCytDVj7VdtiQoQa3YHRmxSGu10xAnY24iSP9YFnYU40i6N/sskiY@lqfhdnubSHmTwf8ykvlFTQju64dumReHaY67Au60jLu12L9VjbaYMKtJRbLIuLVZYyFVRiGcWVv27DfZjx8C6JlRVgRLJ4iDMzAn3KEPb1K1PGRfQWERFf2pakh29xnQeuDXsUlMNr1uExleEMkHS8Wpq4pUxy2mPwtmmwSBq5kCbMuGm3K5uMttg0WAwelEYxEAJJBr6DZcswL1gxi0FYmBUAlhvQUYzihkYWeqKM1c7ei8bCp2vRRjcqMsh8DN2CL1IwGyPWGYFpkWIkXy2XSLilokqN6PTr8Qe0a2SjDBXKyxTiGBIeRq60XLDysV1mBTFwjAOY/PqY9NBMFWSUL4WrJtqNpoZJsojMfcd2LXQQh0snyMF0lSRh9qg7Wu3PpbY9H9qlZaRQrl@la6tJhYsqZFLY5unh0dt3t7/vnP168U3zWJd7x7cK9jYF79Qkn5xevSCxiDMSGaZj9q9VqF5R7L2uYm9ThWDgpF2ScbqFDFq8X19cxzxTrsxWKW6RL7N2p1jkpkqWdAIgtgseMZq9W02uvf2RtEPsdIvyQ2lAvoRzVUxMgIL/u0kyNlTioaplo5B1AXAqSgGiHgr9NdyAuXt1P9F5DMYDZhTZKjYgCMtxjEkYn4SQQnDCwNAyKhLQT/RdFi6i48vbxSKBmbs6Ay/6Wrn1I4c6P@@RbubdhpkJ2pj@pTZC0BaLJDF1U23m2FAi/geT0w2TsQy/P/xwbmMxFoEGr6fXruM4EE7gCryqt5z/GX8pGD58LUY1b5EBeLPxw6PPvcBVNR1THJZ1fNCnJx57ADg@PTvqsAlkR79RhrbUh3k4Cpd2EqfUAmhcqb5KcAbn7iUy1hdiccLahhXH5NRMQDEeEBc@VBWOk2XeiObLtR0gkvioSiFIEx@hmvyBF9HM7AAzG20YcMTkX4SFqn3Y7jPUIgABEoqNHKRhq0VOSfGylayFrOVTGa4Q1K8WGdYualmvR9ZTFWbQQVFyF4ovQXFddgYZz7Razh8T/KuQHwAJUgVH07hIoNs0W7SXLdwhrJFjnlo@n5gm7Sd2BNEsQ1tsiFPLEtscOP5WW@FhUR8g9B0JfaJ1xGwgCfGVvUiSzJ2VlW8rfwS@nHlXzeBKneIScwsYjAaIv2C5WMapqSm2jcygXgGsCuaiVEI8Bp6z/wuNy@7CFC3JBEwfo1PQw0HI2tjgARyaB3pDHaBahZcJg6wbUC@EJxaQlqQb5JAuoholdALm6U1LRWPlye/gSfwH9HF42jf83KntOl0qdjCTbQDPNsIDtCR1XjT4tw14b6v@X9t92VBuCfgyQ8pKZZxT/2xirbJUsRoO962qA91Im2rpFXWR5m6OC@uHZnMx0A49kq4XMq5lVFA1gWUoDlMp9qVSJ2ubvlMyB0kWLioW8ACJGxKSK/a9RjFrtejG1ushdCT64RvqyxvKrN3XnRzsMeHNYupIZpr5qyJXUVLGjmgKhUHd0iDKp5BXMXVjCGrbI9ruRn2bxfUX0XBBYGrPPbHn2CjToREbQCgcxmwQKC89a3tIR2GhHrI9dbsVTZb6jrIsaFttehYyl0i/ehthqUUl9vR1e8WiTrU7W1hYL@NbeOhs8CD2dRsL8y2udQgT6EJoAdQqkzJp0L6B2yCC/F6P5EmiqLSub7RgtKhliTc/JObNdmJ2f7hod/uifxCbNYfEHYPGPN1LX9IuWA9Yzy1ZJixQ78I567lwxlwd7P0kegBptIYNAoSS3r4acRTlRLQ3dCTXnkVtTScg/pvrB4ImyRW4S1AixlIE3/FqMYuzuJ2zdAG9Nk8KnrKH8BF4Y@MFXF6LeBpnsGa5SOO04CHeNuAkL9hDzGbhfQxAKQjhBZuH6QrC5/E1jqJ3d8g4UEFM5KukwF8XSHmZ8BSkp2OUyjXK9HUlZE08ynsZ6bxsSAkb1FAOXeTDBGvoI3idjpN4zG4rs29LKU/4TTRwmpLKmSEK6/XUu0XwhoR2NNOfyzw4oGBdK5CY9Gp5MahnxQOmH/6BfgxwaV/@sNdiAnDAag0lDdpMy4YowxErVWn2RB1A7E4A1UbrloZwKDG0FuNFn83jebTEMEvZ8Pbg/3Vl@Be4MlSu7GzxJZC@SFcOXmZfaN1iMk4fsBrAKxGeKqA72@ysXkr3VObRBZTmtar0h75sqw0H@kqZSsr1X/@b9TIHaWLK9X67r6Nr7fA6Nqiybn36py88qgeubjyIa9RuPWUqJAxKHAW11VqaxBWI6HbLZcLkz@Ce@HlMb0hr3jG9d5HLTuvdPUK19Qdef0@j5URcLQKtw@rqBWjzLpXKC4pdnoW9WuN7JYheE@qvlzxvW8nbs8o@wCtX79Pgf2iI0DB84lZE5SWhbIf03sgDD1Fr18UmiRoEEf9ikh6E6MqTANrH8SSEJAmeqQ6TpzDJx/RjUxgVUKbau1Ebe04csdgLt10UVtZA6AblDw7zkKfYrLIwm0Y2Ce104Pu9hT9r0T0U/5/IdMia@nXv@Xsx4zmDf2HK4jB/xOUJeDuN/w0)

Expanded code:

```
;= s (+" " PROMPT)
;= i ~1
;= r ""
;WHILE <(= i + 1 i) (LENGTH s)
  =r + r 
     + (=g (GET s i 1))
     IF (?g " ")
       ;=i (+ 2 i) 
       + ((GET s i 1) 
          (GET s (- i 1) 1))
       ""
OUTPUT (GET r 1 (LENGTH r))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Ḳµḣ2Uo)K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcwxDsIwDIXhqzxlQ2LiGswMjFFxSJEbV4lF25WFg3RlQkLqDCcpFwkJkid/ev@FmKec1@X5fq3LvDvIZp8/9@/tcczZ@KKCQSKfzBZGfZtQzgaQTRMab5kpnKlipCvFRFBPcG1MCh0ETKrlDXFl0vja@qf6XseakkDVRMaO4SR2ViubHw)

### How it works

```
Ḳµḣ2Uo)K - Main link. Takes a string
Ḳ        - Split by spaces
 µ    )  - Over each word:
  ḣ2     -   Take the first two characters
    U    -   Reverse them
     o   -   Logical Or, overwriting the first two characters of the word
       K - Join with spaces
```

Comment: Now that I/O can be lists, it's 5 bytes `ḣ2Uo)` (or something like that)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 51 bytes

```
lambda s:' '.join(w[1::-1]+w[2:]for w in s.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BCoMwEEX3PcXgRqVUsN0JPUnrItVJkzJmQjI0evo0bgrC38znzeP7TQy7W9b3Zya1vGYFcaih7j5sXZMe/TBc@vGcHtdh1BwggXUQu@jJStO22QfrpNFNZZCIIXGguWrb078XYyOUKAeo4gaTUUTo3nigAn4xRAQxCNqGKCCJgVCk1MC6/E5mtx/l3su6y9nhDjGvC0GZuSg5cOXIPw)

Comment: -3 bytes by using a full program: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BDoJADEX3c4qGFWgw4spwFcOCYHGalOlkpgiexY0Lde11vI1DMPnJb9rf197f_qZW3OMzWWKEqsYZuzzLsteofXn87n0gp_kmp1NV12XVbOl0qJteAhCQS_Kj5sUueqbkRbHuPRPhXz6-ziKzwCSBz0YtRUhqHWAbb9DZlhndBU3AK4aIoBahpxAVdBJgVE1tkD7lO7tQzsZ7nReIOFwGIvPAkH4aWjVmPfsD

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:' '.join([''.join(list(i[:2])[::-1])+i[2:]for i in s.split()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcbBCoAgDADQXxmeHJGQ3QZ9iXgwQlqYSvPS169L7/T6O85WV9UMG5R070cCITBg3NW42mD@FJZhOZCPGIjmJeLEwVPM7QEGriBOeuFhMaLqBw)

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEADAryxdMqKgugm9pDxspblhq7Reer0Fc5z0Zh95Km5eS8B7OxBEV1D1VyRWtAxad4NpaRm1cfEBAmKQXlKgrJqmpIc4K6fq7EnghwwW5YXdYwiWT1v/6wM) (although there is already a 48 byte answer)

Comment: There's already two other Python answers. I did this to see how far I could get without starting from another answer.

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 26 bytes

Prompts for sentence

```
(⌽¨2↑¨s),¨2↓¨s←(s≠' ')⊂s←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##JYw7DsIwEER7n2I7BwkK4BRIIM5ghTWOtGQj2@LTUoSPEAIhekouQcNRfJGwCdIWb2Z2xlQ0WOwM8XKQkwmhyJt0fc6mqb6NldBkLjRU6XiwTZYun@97lOr79x16/Q4fgvKRhXR6adC9dN63WpqNdFRjlXZIxLBhTwutREdXBJAzJaAJO8idIcJyiV3qcY0@IESHYAsfIsQNA2GMYgNb6eSuXfuPVVXctmNcYhsyb1cElv3KxC7XPw)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 55 bytes

```c
f(char*s){for(;s-1;s=index(s,32)+1)*s^=s[1]^(s[1]=*s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHbjpswEEDf9yumSJXsXNRmV32oaPpS9SuSrOQ64xjVwcgzLWyj/HrpGMguShEgmMvxsceuT9b2vVPWm7QgfXExqZLWm5K2VX3ETtHq6VEvN3pBz1vabQ7PKr@3Ulte@6pmOJuqVhouDyDXgAFGYtodYAuXwmMIEdqYwrFYQcG@IpDb1ICGXnJDCFifMCcT/sZECOwRXJWIgdsIAZklDNFJi/WZNaCahruMijXmXIzdOYD4nw3ndHEtZ0rYNWgZj5MV@mwV28nKs3CogtqAQbHydmaFabTyjFC5bNVyBAyjlYvSIlbCerPKqIg5N1pF959VrAU0ulmP9iemSW3ffX/cd5@/yfMpd8z@n27dsktQ@fCHGUnbx3L6/CJr/8Ho1G3D@sMUWLxGSlguh2o9wMbJzaYnvHGCQ9GhvMv/@OXcjjjJASnWsITNrETitnlRuWYFrN8SbojpexjKYq@zuV8v77AxRFLzLoPPzQTGGadJUuZUsS/e076A9VeYvuRVywHyCsam2zFn4mECXB@u/V/rgjlRv27/AQ)

Inputs a pointer to a string.
Performs the reversing in place.

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 34 bytes

```
[[X,Y|R]|A]^[[Y,X|R]|O]:-A^O.
A^A.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCoMwEADAu6/Yo8ImD/BS8gK1J2VJGqnSBtZuSAJe/HtKexuYmITlpfIZaiWacbnu9jLWES04/zzYXhk36MY4o@tNAfn3ziwewZ@SePPWjdgAwLFGDrm0a5Hj8ZRtzwgTwtj9N6bwKe3U6foF)

-6 bytes thanks to Jo King

I/O as list of list of codepoints.

Comment: `g`  can be replaced with `+` [like so](https://tio.run/##RY2xCoMwFEX3fMUbE3zJB7gUJ8doJyVokSptIPaFJODSf09Di3Q6w7mH6wM5esh42JzNgOP7OlVmxKFQsWbWtdwX72xMvMIGtVA58bawlkui/XandYtcYysUu0g4t3@HYJ6bc4RwUHDrhKAFMgDQc/flmSSEDqH/SR/sK/G@vH0A). Actually, you can avoid `maplist` and the second function altogether for [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYuxCsMgFAD3fMUbFZ5@QJbglNGkU4JoCU1oBdMnKmTJv1vaUjrdwXExUaC7yIev1ZgJ5/NiT2WdMTNOb9e2Fcpp2SinZC2sR81bsRTarzdat8w09lw2nYB9icHnwv4NwTy2EAjhoBRWi6A5NgCg3fDhbykIA8L4jTH5Z2Ejl/UF)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 90 bytes

```
k=l.length
i=\{k=0:[],[1...k]\}
L=join(32,l)
f(l)=\{L[i-1]=32:L[i],L[i]=32:L[i+2],L[i+1]\}
```

Takes in space separated words as a list of codepoints, and returns another list of codepoints.

Probably a terrible way of doing this but whatever.

Here's a Python [program](https://tio.run/##LcXBCsMgDADQXwk9xUMPY5fRX2k8iNMqSCIxO5Sxb3eFDR68floRvj@6ztm1smFehMgEMlFL2fDXe5jiLvrE6CCLQoTKl/4ydN7t23rzHyKtRzH/3y1uTit1wCUwpDBOiCW0lvhIXw) that takes in a string as input and outputs a list of codepoints that Desmos can read. (e.g.: `hello world` -> `o\to f\left(\left[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100\right]\right)`)

Here's a Python [program](https://tio.run/##LYvNDsIgEIRfhXBiE2zYYn/wVSgnYwXTAEE8@PQI1GRnZ3YnX/xmG7xcYyolJuczo3R4BeeZvtvE2sMDkD0k4olrEz@ZgZ5vl8UM73i4SnAKBqCU7XjsWaO4csSZo5iqT1yO3drZo@BqaaluFHh2I/aukkqdxfoXdgKFbHlL7mmz@QE) that takes in the outputted list of codepoints from Desmos and converts it into a string. (e.g.: `\left[104,116,105,115,32,115,105,32,110,97,32,97,101,115,121,32,104,99,97,108,108,101,110,103,101\right]` -> `htis si na aesy hcallenge`)

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hyggwonipm)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xpcnpftppa)

Answer (score 2):

## [Chocolate](https://github.com/Steffan153/chocolate) \$\ge\$ commit [8b0b99b](https://github.com/Steffan153/chocolate/commit/8b0b99b882f5fa59db2d7463aa6bda370fa2bedc), 5 bytes

```
γỴD_Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://chocolate-lang.netlify.app/#WyLOs+G7tERf4biiIiwiW1wiaGVsbG9cIiwgXCJ3b3JsZFwiXSJd)

Previously:

### [Chocolate](https://github.com/Steffan153/chocolate), 8 bytes

```
γC⅃:2_DD
```

[Try it online!](https://chocolate-lang.netlify.app/#WyLOs0PihYM6Ml9ERCIsIltcImhlbGxvXCIsIFwid29ybGRcIl0iXQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 17 bytes

```
' '/{2/(-1%\' '}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxCoAwDAXQq/xF6iJFz@MiNbWFQiQJdhDPHrs93sUta5J6m3tAiO8W52Wd9uEvugs9JEqwQshV1GCd0chsNDiDjlTQWc4f)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda s:[x[1]+x[0]+x[2:]for x in s.split()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUaHYKroi2jBWuyLaAEQYWcWm5RcpVChk5ikU6xUX5GSWaGjG/v8PAA)

Outputs as a list of words.

Comment: You may take input as a list of words instead, reducing it to [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKroi2jBWuyLaAEQYWcWm5RcpVChk5ikUx/4vKMrMK9FI0@CKVkpMykvMS1TSUSrOBBL5laVKsVyamv8B).

Comment: [43](https://tio.run/##DcJBDoMgEAXQq/ydkEYTdUfSk1AW0wpCgiNxWODpqS@v3DWevPaANz490/HdCGJss7Mx4@xezS7GhfNCQ2LIJCWnqrTr5UpcVVBDjUnwJIYnufGLlLPn3Q9a9z8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I/O as an array of words.

```
ËÅíDÎ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=uA&code=y8XtRM4&input=ImVydmVyc2UgaHRlIGlmcnN0IHd0byBlbHR0ZXJzIGZvIGFlY2ggb3dyZCIKLVM)

```
ËÅíDÎ     :Implicit input of array
Ë         :Map each D
 Å        :  Slice off the first character
  í       :  Interleave with
   DÎ     :    First character of D
```

### 6 bytes

```
Ëò vÔ¬
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=uA&code=y/IgdtSs&input=ImVydmVyc2UgaHRlIGlmcnN0IHd0byBlbHR0ZXJzIGZvIGFlY2ggb3dyZCIKLVM)

```
Ëò vÔ¬     :Implicit input of array
Ë          :Map
 ò         :  Partitions of length 2
   v       :  Modify first element
    Ô      :    Reverse
     ¬     :  Join
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 16 bytes

```
{1Se[2/(W%\+}%S*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5BCoMwEPxKWBCKUkp7bKFPKIgHD1FKsGtjWY0koVrEt6dJxMvszuwws81H9G5xy7lAfjkdyqTK1qRI3XrNb5yDRCIFDCal6QU142BlZ7wQQQweUJifH40URDi8Mbo0flEb9LqVAdtOGxvYFNIIrfVnv6k2JjRy69gqxtHOe4UacLcpNfcUspTuhY1OqOvlWaRVDux4Z1Bl/vlH6v4)

A function which takes an array of strings as input. Link includes test cases.

## Explanation

```
{1Se[2/(W%\+}%S* # whole function which takes an array of inputs
{           }%   # for each value in the input
   e[            # pad to length
 1               # `1` using
  S              # `S`paces
     2/          # split into chunks of length `2`
       (         # get the first split chunk
        W%       # map by `W` (shorthand for -1), reversing
          \+     # swap to the beginning of the stack and add to the rest of the array
              S* # join this array by `S`paces
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 23 bytes

```
a:
[]$1 []$2=>$2 $1/$ _
```

Performs metathesis on the first 2 characters of each whitespace-delimited series of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 23 bytes

```
s/(^| +)(.)(.)/\1\3\2/g
```

Can be shortened if one assumes that there are no consecutive spaces, or that the input starts with a space.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlWbSSrqtS7IKlpSVpuhbbi_U14moUtDU19EBIP8YwxjjGSD8dIgtVtGBXSUZmsYICECfmKaQmFlcqJGck5uSk5qWnQlQAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>18</s> 19 bytes

```
irf[' =fo[pfoo0]p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zKC1aXcE2LT@6IC0/3yC2IFbh//@i1LLUouJUhZKMVIW0zKLiEoWS8nwA)

This relies on the fact that each word will have at least two characters, which is noted in the description. It also assumes the input will not start or end with a space, and that there won't be multiple spaces in a row.  That assumption is currently an open question.  If that doesn't turn out to be OK, this approach won't work.

```
ir                 - read input as codepoints, reverse stack
  f                - reverse first two chars
   [             ] - for each char/codepoint on the stack...
    ' =            - is the current char a space?
       fo          - pull char forward and print
         [p   0]p  - if/then
           foo     - flip the top two chars and print them
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 164 bytes

```
|t:String|t.split(" ").filter(|i|i.len()>0).map(|i|{let k=i.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>();[&k[1..2],&k[0..1],&k[2..],&[' ']].concat()}).flatten().collect::<String>();
```

Strings will have a extra space at the end.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVFLTiMxENVsOUWlF2BLGQtYjRIIh0CaTRRFliljC8du7ArJKMlJZpMFHIDjMNeYC0y5m-ErLKv9eR-_rvp9n5eF9o82wkL7KOQmIIGF84cl2e8_nu63NLqk7OP1llRpgyfRQCOV9YEwi63fehWQdZNjqRa6rTedxc25V8bpXIRUJoWAhkajs59ozuaTiZDj6eHN9ESp09mQN8dKnXSbU6V4nR7B0WzGsmg0Cbnj54Imqs-88epjVa8-659vf8cHwMOmDIKw0NzogkPAdcsKvJpnLMtAEnyEOzSDaceuQzQOQ0iwSjlcNUNo0NVjWtWjHL7hkfMFeOoIqMsv4F_kPPEaq8oRI8VD1KCRQWf-g-88Mt5hLgjkEKzPhYBWCbhoXNECybKzcTVLHyX3bEcI3lb2ihJg6Nk28VPM5qgfkrYtrWvSFLF6prRehFqahaZq28E1a8Jq0sPJdvA7n0puZHcxg80L0HLxKcSBaDajix3UDzPta90VpXnpWiSk_NyE8YuTLgUzDcRXWoW34qP6Wb472PW93-_79R8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>51</s> 29 bytes

```factor
[ [ 0 1 pick exchange ] map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZCxTsQwDIb3PsXPA4BgPSRWxMKCmE43RMElUdM4TQztqbpnL06LjoGTzooyRP4@/3FrrHBe3t9eXp93KDR8UbRU0FGOFJAyiRxT9lEwjHhsmrmB1jDOcBQCY@QcPnDClbrB7RPIBWbwqMTZIs4X6DERZMoR1pkQKH7SJedqcaLtxSMaGFLC2V/i7Mz0TbmQugmtz0UgIyPoV/QZ3Ook62ryGnxLljfCCcG3lRiFQWEjWtZJSmjyv@ApyVSDc6SqZJ76oJ25N/I/@jpkJWpwpqrcCG4rsVrn62u8YFWqOTXLHnvc4wHJ2w406RrrDg/oTcJhqXcRY7u75Qc)

-22 bytes from OP allowing lists after I answered.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 148 bytes

```
class H {public static void main(String[]a){String l="";for(String s:a[0].split(" ")){l+=s.charAt(1);l+=s.charAt(0);l+=s.substring(2)+" ";}a[0]=l;}}
```

Comment: You can apply quite a bit of golfing here: you don’t need public on the class, you can use the args  list instead of hard coding the input, the args variable name can be just “a”. Be sure to check out the Java tips page

Comment: @Seggan thank you for the tips

Comment: Do you need a class? I thought a method was legal. `a=> ...`

Comment: @JollyJoker (That is a lambda expression.) Methods, lambdas, and full programs are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
⪫Ｅ⪪Ｓ ⭆ι⎇‹μ²§ι¬μλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwEETvfsXS0wbixasnjxUVof5ASLcmkCZhs7b69TFFLwMz7zHWGbbJhFrv7KPgOfmIV5NxyMEL9jG/ZJCGnqg0dNC1/PVN8hoexNHwBy9UCs4aDk04SR9Hem/4lgRn1bag1P9AHWtlWogLgTiCyXMRkDVBIJE2Q5qAjHWwJh53db@ELw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   Ｓ                Input string
  ⪪                 Split on spaces
 Ｅ                  Map over words
      ι             Current word
     ⭆              Map over letters and join
         μ          Current index
        ‹           Is less than
          ²         Literal integer `2`
       ⎇            If true then
            ι       Current word
           §        Indexed by
              μ     Current index
             ¬      Logical Not (i.e 1 - index)
               λ    Else current letter
⪫                   Join with spaces
                    Implicitly print
```

Note: A trailing newline is needed in the input field otherwise Charcoal thinks you're supplying multiple inputs.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 15 bytes

```
{2coq<-0ap++}ww
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BjsIwDEX3PYXFFlVCs2U0N2ERyg@uZOo2MRMQ4uzFno6UjfOev//5XgR1uWNdDlV21P/Q7njsT@vra9Dluz@keb9/t7auDBGlpkUuYYFj1OZjZzxW8pcmQqpPGjiJYLoiRDYndaQpUYJDHv5hV/CLUkHGoDyWamRNSWDm36TZwwaOi9vBstlsoDGH3UwJstlZPd1tL3Tp5tke0UcnRIzq4yZulFuySPrD0UgRexvWHPgD)

Unfortunately

```
 q<-"\b.."~a
```

Doesn't work as expected

```
{
 2co # Chunks of 2
 q<- # Quoted reverse
 0ap # Apply to first block
 ++  # Concat
}ww  # Apply to each word
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
+L.(d1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X9tHTyPF8P//6GilEiUdpQwgzgTiYqVYHYVoZGYikJkHYaYCmYlgGR2lSohQMlQvSDgHilPBOnSU0sHs2FgA)

Accepts a list of lists of characters ("words"), and returns a list of lists of characters.

```
+L.(d1
 L      Left map over the input:
  .(d1  Pop and return the second letter of each word
+       Append the popped letter to the remaining letters
```

---

If a list of strings is required as input/output:

#### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
m.itdhd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1cvsyQlI@X//2ilkozMYiUdBSUImZgHIlMTiytBdHJGYk5Oal56qlIsAA)

Answer (score 1):

## SM83, 19 bytes

Input pointer in `hl`, output pointer in `de`.

```
46 23 2A 12 13 78 12 13
2A 12 13 B7 C8 FE 20 20
F7 18 ED
```

```
f:
    ld b,[hl]       // 46       // y = *in
    inc hl          // 23       // in++
    ld a,[hl+]      // 2A       // x = *(in++)
    ld [de],a       // 12       // *out = x
    inc de          // 13       // out++
    ld a,b          // 78       // x = y
    ld [de],a       // 12       // *out = x
    inc de          // 13       // out++
l:
    ld a,[hl+]      // 2A       // x = *(in++)
    ld [de],a       // 12       // *out = x
    inc de          // 13       // out++
    or a            // B7       // is x NUL?
    ret z           // C8       // Y: return
    cp ' '          // FE 20    // is x SPACE?
    jr nz,l         // 28 F7    // N: continue copying
    jr f            // 18 ED    // Y: start all over
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 14 bytes

```
[[0 1 exch]"!]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCsIwEEX3PcVXhChY0K0L8R6li9BOTDXthGS09fQxqcj8zbw386Po7kl9Sk1zwhm0dLbdbtp0u5hqXwHKknOMmYPrVdnFDhE5egLp@EFntXM03Wm1gd4UIkEswQwhCmRmOBLJGGzyT2dL26/Me1lKGU9UJPMyOhgOo5bVq@pQNZf1PsJA5XnwMOGIXSAfMGqfUV1f/4Jf0haavg)

Alternatively, `0 1`  can be `0:#+`, but it's the same byte count.

### Explanation

Uses the classic golf `map` → `"!` (each execute).

```
[[0 1 exch]"!]
[            ]    anonymous lambda
 [        ]"!     execute this code on each cell
  0 1 exch        exchange indices 0 and 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 39 bytes

```lua
return(...):gsub("%f[%w](.)(.)","%2%1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCsMwDEPv@QpTKKQwAttxvzJ2yBqnCXhxcZy1@/oundBBSOJR80dsZdbMBaJ1zk2HoDYp/3xfanvZYYyPcXtaN3UPl2G8jddhOrAEs6VMCCoNITCskotaG21mJ@iDnbqg/46ERAwbCwWjKVfo9gXQ1y/MyRNhWdAIflBq5yWEmKUq6MZAqNpr4Nj/czopwayr7ieEC54D8/4miCxvr@YH)

Comment: Not every day you see Lua around here. Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 10 bytes

```
gR`^..`RV_
```

Inputs an array as multiple command-line arguments; outputs an array in Pip array syntax. [Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsImdSYF4uLmBSVl8iLCIiLCIiLCItcCB0aGUgcXVpY2sgYnJvd24gZm94Il0=)

#### Explanation

```
gR`^..`RV_
g           In array of command-line args,
 R          replace
  `   `     all matches of this regex:
   ^         Beginning of string
    ..       followed by two characters
       RV_  with the reverse of the match
```

---

An interesting alternate 10-byter can be achieved by porting [math junkie's Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249585/16766):

```
{aPK1}._Mg
        Mg  To each command-line arg, map this function:
{aPK1}       Pick the character at index 1 out of the string
      ._     and concatenate it to the rest of the string
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsInthUEsxfS5fTWciLCIiLCIiLCItcCB0aGUgcXVpY2sgYnJvd24gZm94Il0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 23 bytes

```
' '/{(\(@[\\]\+}[/]' '*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDADAr3SD6MAX/AdlMFiEhKSmNDIY31698U7uZWRpl5o5cOHx6LeImHB9Y0h/LWZCN8kg0EpQmgwFnQydVP8GLkB7rjBZjg8)

Answer (score 1):

## [str](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/str), 16 bytes

```
gg~:o;d' =?ogg~:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky4p@v8/Pb3OKt86RV3B1j4fxP7/vyQjs1gBiBLzFFITiysVkjMSc3JS89JTFQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 10 bytes

```
r$:o84*)0.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v0jFKt/CREvTQO////@6xUWpZalFxakKJRmpCmmZRcUlCiXl@Qo5qSUlQGGF/DSF1MTkDIXy/KIUAA)

**Explanation**

```
r           # reverse stack to get input in correct order
 $          # swap the top 2 letters of the stack
  :o        # print a copy of the letter
    84*)0.  # jump to coordinates x=previousLetterCharCode>32, y=0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 34 bytes

```arturo
$[a][map a'w[t:w\0w\0:w\1w\1:t w]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?MTHQLT)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
⍚⍜(↙2)⇌
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAg4o2a4o2cKOKGmTIp4oeMCgpmIHsiaGVsbG8iICJ3b3JsZCJ9CmYgeyJyZXZlcnNlIiAiZmlyc3QiICJ0d28ifQo=)

```
⍚⍜(↙2)⇌
⍚        # apply function to each item in list, unboxing and re-boxing
 ⍜       # apply one function 'under' another
  (↙2)   # take first two
      ⇌  # reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [morsecco](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26119/72726):  <s>110</s>  100 bytes

```
.    . - ..- - -- - . - .-. - - .-.. --.. --. - .- .   -. - .  -.-.  - . -.-. . -.-. .. --. - .- ---
```

Saved some bytes by combining three `-.-.` operations. Explanation:

- `.    . - ..- -` to `E`nter an empty cell and `U`se stdin for `T`oken reading
- `-- - . - .-.` to `M`ark the beginning of the loop and `R`ead next word
- `- - .-.. --.. --.` to test the `L`ength of the token to `Z`eroskip the loop
- `- .- - .- .   -. - .`  drops the length and prepares the `C` sequence: `C`ut the first two letters, than `C`ut the first and `C`oncatenate both in reverse order
- `-.-.  - . -.-. .` execute that sequence, and `C`oncatenate the swapped word parts
- `-.-. .. --.` `C`oncatenates to the previous word and `G`oes to the mark
- `- .- ---` after jumping out of the loop, `O`utput the line

Answer (score 1):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)’s type system, 90 bytes

```typescript
type X<L>=L extends[`${infer A}${infer B}${infer C}`,...infer R]?`${B}${A}${C} ${X<R>}`:""
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgPAGQHwF4FQgD2BAdgEwGcBtAAwBIBvAS1wDMIAnKAQQF8raHmAhDm+kygBhNqQA0AOmlchAJQC6AfgqU+VdlVFQq8OUjEAuAETGAsAChLoSFABeUFLDjFjACwgAbTwHtj44wB3H0ZPfGMFJEsAemioeIA9JUsgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 11 characters

```
\X<L1>?=?$1
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ gema '\X<L1>?=?$1' <<< 'reverse the first two letters of each word'
erverse hte ifrst wto eltters fo aech owrd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/PybCxsfQzt7WXsXw//@i1LLUouJUhZKMVIW0zKLiEoWS8nyFnNSSEqCwQn6aQmpicoZCeX5RCgA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lZFNb9swDIbP9a/gjLRKD4GRYj01brtDDgM2dBh62JAYhmbTlTHFMiR2yZD1t2ekhH4c2kMBQ6b0PiRfSr90MIcWG6s9wuwTEAaqGx2wnGZHK2XQWgdb522rqlKhka3bylZkMn0A/vQAqMNfaIy2Foc7FNgQK6GHQYNGFk3zKEqqxz/oAwIZhK73gYC2DiwS8TG4jgs2Rjqnxj7RhhD6TugtOUCb6M5xB6bZWPI1jrQTX25AKeXcbmOZ8htNUi3K4syh5CbZdVGW9Lpefv12@7OuBVbZaZaNvh@oA/UPjmcfzwO88j/jdT0oUJ@H8Z74/x3DvZVguRuxIWw5vPmtsoyNQC8Qr5BP9h@eLn11XT3kF9A6drFiKVI5lCW88ARVBScnqYLYy4587FTmkykUbqTiDje6CL6JAajD@sfiy/zyqryazA8KFovFc@nTnPPfMR3bjZlFMVG8L9br4SHn02RBov3zNKlJFYEpxIkeOR7pDTRNx8/p4nWJw5bf8fAf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ıÞṅ1Q
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY49DoJAEIXvsrUWWnkNa0Kx4uCSDDtkdxA8gHcwMTFbaIilJbVewpKbOAvSvPfm78tcOza1tbTuEjX0QaXhUXO-3Dw_r_dt6M-r7d3vMv_vhu8lUQYQSS1UQw734mwKLzaKtiKg_UksMxoR7AEkOziC8zBuR80L5zlWTSQhMMtYEuXjfWYmfsRXFbcznizMS0RtiZFErtSs0unBHw)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
ıÞṅ1Q  # Implicit input
ı      # Map over each word:
 Þ     #  Sort the characters by:
  ṅ    #   Get the 0-based iteration index
   1Q  #   And check if it's not equal to 1 
       # Implicit output
```